# Referencing style for springer documentclass[default,iicol]{sn-jnl}

Tags: bibliographies, two-column, documentclass, springernature, bst

I am using the new nature class from Springer, which is available on this https://www.springernature.com/gp/authors/campaigns/latex-author-support

I am having trouble in selecting the bibliography style for the document class iicol. In the main text, it is mentioned to use 'Default with double column layout', but I am unable to find the same in bst folder.

This is how the main document looks like

```
    %Version 2.1 April 2023
% See section 11 of the User Manual for version history
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%                                                                 %%
%% Please do not use \input{...} to include other tex files.       %%
%% Submit your LaTeX manuscript as one .tex document.              %%
%%                                                                 %%
%% All additional figures and files should be attached             %%
%% separately and not embedded in the \TeX\ document itself.       %%
%%                                                                 %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%\documentclass[referee,sn-basic]{sn-jnl}% referee option is meant for double line spacing

%%=======================================================%%
%% to print line numbers in the margin use lineno option %%
%%=======================================================%%

%%\documentclass[lineno,sn-basic]{sn-jnl}% Basic Springer Nature Reference Style/Chemistry Reference Style

%%======================================================%%
%% to compile with pdflatex/xelatex use pdflatex option %%
%%======================================================%%

%%\documentclass[pdflatex,sn-basic]{sn-jnl}% Basic Springer Nature Reference Style/Chemistry Reference Style


%%Note: the following reference styles support Namedate and Numbered referencing. By default the style follows the most common style. To switch between the options you can add or remove “Numbered” in the optional parenthesis. 
%%The option is available for: sn-basic.bst, sn-vancouver.bst, sn-chicago.bst, sn-mathphys.bst. %  
 
%%\documentclass[sn-nature]{sn-jnl}% Style for submissions to Nature Portfolio journals
%%\documentclass[sn-basic]{sn-jnl}% Basic Springer Nature Reference Style/Chemistry Reference Style
%%documentclass[sn-mathphys,Numbered]{sn-jnl}% Math and Physical Sciences Reference Style
%%\documentclass[sn-aps]{sn-jnl}% American Physical Society (APS) Reference Style
%%\documentclass[sn-vancouver,Numbered]{sn-jnl}% Vancouver Reference Style
%%\documentclass[sn-apa]{sn-jnl}% APA Reference Style 
%%\documentclass[sn-chicago]{sn-jnl}% Chicago-based Humanities Reference Style
%%\documentclass[default]{sn-jnl}% Default
\documentclass[default,iicol]{sn-jnl}% Default with double column layout

%%%% Standard Packages
%%<additional latex packages if required can be included here>


\end{appendices}

%%===========================================================================================%%
%% If you are submitting to one of the Nature Portfolio journals, using the eJP submission   %%
%% system, please include the references within the manuscript file itself. You may do this  %%
%% by copying the reference list from your .bbl file, paste it into the main manuscript .tex %%
%% file, and delete the associated \verb+\bibliography+ commands.                            %%
%%===========================================================================================%%

\bibliography{sn-bibliography}% common bib file
%% if required, the content of .bbl file can be included here once bbl is generated
%%\input sn-article.bbl


\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436/184389) Have you checked the documentation PDF that is provided with the class? If not, look on page 12 (Section 8.3). They list which `.bst` file (located in the `bst` folder when downloading the sources) should be used depending on the journal you want to submit to. If you're still unsure, you should check the author guidelines specifically provided by the journal you plan to submit to.

Comment: I want to submit in Signal, Image and Video Processing journal. [link](https://www.springer.com/journal/11760/submission-guidelines#Instructions%20for%20Authors) .  It is mentioned to use the document class as iicol. Could suggest me the necessary changes for bibliography style and the bibliography? Thanks

Comment: From what is described in the "References" section of the link you provided, my guess would be to use the sn-mathphys with a `\bibliographystyle{sn-mathphys}` before your `\bibliography` command. Of course, before doing that, retrieve the proper `.bst` in the `bst` folder provided by the editor

Comment: Thanks. It worked @KersouMan

Answer (score 0):

As mention in the comment section above, add \bibliographystyle{sn-mathphys} before \bibliography if you want the number format for citation. For other format, follow bst file names or reference string in different \documentclass{}. Repeated the comment so that users can have better visual on answer.